# I'm making a registry tree view. But im having issues with speed

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization

In the application im working on right now i have to have a tree view with the paths to registries i have read from a .reg file. That works fine, i have an array with every path found in the file. But the issues come with adding the paths to the tree view. I found a handy function online for plotting a list of paths to the tree. And it actually works fine, but even just plotting 500 paths to the tree takes a LOONG time. I tried optimizing it a bit but it still takes to long to plot every single registry like in the Windows registry editor. And so im pretty bewildered by how they even made the tree view in the registry editor work.

I tried replacing all the foreach loops in the tree plotting function with for loops but it didnt help.
Then i tried replacing the for loops with Parallel.For but it simply didnt work.
And i tried making my own function that plots a list of paths but i couldnt figure it out.
And lastly i tried elevating the applications cpu priority and setting it to x86 and bringing it to release and not debug. It barely helped

I was thinking about having a system where it only plots the items you have expanded. but my brain is not big enough to figure this out.

Should i spent more time of my life figuring that out or is there a better way? Or is there a solution i havent found.

Since somebody asked for code here you go:

```
private void PopulateTreeView(TreeView treeView, string[] paths)
    {
        TreeNode lastNode = null;
        string subPathAgg;
        for (int x = 0; x < paths.Count(); x++)
        {
            subPathAgg = string.Empty;
            string[] tmpstr = paths[x].Split(@"\".ToCharArray());
            for (int y = 0; y < tmpstr.Count(); y++)
            {
                subPathAgg += tmpstr[y] + (@"\".ToCharArray());
                TreeNode[] nodes = treeView.Nodes.Find(subPathAgg, true);
                if (nodes.Length == 0)
                    if (lastNode == null)
                        lastNode = treeView.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, tmpstr[y]);
                    else
                        lastNode = lastNode.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, tmpstr[y]);
                else
                    lastNode = nodes[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code I ended up using:

```cs
private TreeNodeCollection PopulateTreeView(string[] paths)
        {
            TreeNode nodes = new TreeNode();
            try
            {
                TreeNode lastNode = null;
                string subPathAgg;
                var nodeDict = new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>();
                for (int x = 0; x < paths.Count(); x++)
                {
                    var tmpstr = paths[x].Split('\\');
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int y = 0; y < tmpstr.Count(); y++)
                    {
                        sb.Append(tmpstr[y]);
                        sb.Append(@"\");
                        subPathAgg = sb.ToString();
                        if (!nodeDict.TryGetValue(subPathAgg, out var node))
                        {
                            node = lastNode == null ? nodes.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, tmpstr[y]) : lastNode.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, tmpstr[y]);
                            nodeDict[subPathAgg] = node;
                        }
                        lastNode = node;
                    }
                }
            }finally{}
            return nodes.Nodes;
        }
```

Comment: Um, are you able to share some code?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen there you go. i added the code relevant

Comment: Winforms? i guess? If so.... this might help: [TreeView.BeginUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.beginupdate?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen yes

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen that might work. ill try it

Comment: Use a dictionaty to lookup the nodes behind `subPathAgg` instead of using find.

Comment: @CSharpie thank you very much. it made it exponentially faster.  you made it work xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the BeginUpdate which suppresses the repainting.

```
private void PopulateTreeView(TreeView treeView, string[] paths)
{
    treeView.BeginUpdate();
    try
    {
        TreeNode lastNode = null;
        string subPathAgg;
        for (int x = 0; x < paths.Count(); x++)
        {
            subPathAgg = string.Empty;
            string[] tmpstr = paths[x].Split(@"\".ToCharArray());
            for (int y = 0; y < tmpstr.Count(); y++)
            {
                subPathAgg += tmpstr[y] + (@"\".ToCharArray());
                TreeNode[] nodes = treeView.Nodes.Find(subPathAgg, true);
                if (nodes.Length == 0)
                    if (lastNode == null)
                        lastNode = treeView.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, tmpstr[y]);
                    else
                        lastNode = lastNode.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, tmpstr[y]);
                else
                    lastNode = nodes[0];
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        treeView.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

I'd rather use the try/finally here. When something goes wrong. at least the treeview will be invalidated.

Comment: its been running for 4 minutes right now and its not done yet... Any more optimizations i can do?

Comment: I just did some calculations. and its actually about 50% faster. but it will still take a really long time

Comment: Is it slow because of adding all items to the tree? of loading and parsing the items.. What is you don't add them to the tree and time it with a `StopWatch`

Comment: The thing that took a long time was the issue you stated. and the Nodes.Find function took long so instead i put subPathAgg in a dictionary. Courtecy of @CSharpie. Im happy to say it works at a good speed now. thank you for the help

Comment: If you want to i could send the code that worked for me to you. just not sure how

Comment: @Ee0Rk just post the solution you end up using as an answer.

Comment: @CSharpie I agree on that.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen check latest edit